Checkboxes, when one is checked uncheck all others with same class
I have many checkboxes each having the same ID's and Classes.
The input's themselves have the class 'el-checkbox__original'.
<!-- when this is clicked the below divs which have checkboxes appear -->
<div id="bap-service-13" class="bpa-front-si-card">
<div class="bpa-front-si-card__row">
</div>
</div>

<div id="treatment-option-ext" class="bpa-service-extra__item">
  <div class="bpa-sei__header">
    <div class="bpa-sei__left">
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-checkbox">
        <label class="el-checkbox bpa-form-label bpa-custom-checkbox--is-label bpa-front-form-control--checkbox">
          <span class="el-checkbox__input">
            <span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="">
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-body">
        <div class="bpa-se--heading">1.1ml</div>
        <div class="bpa-se--options">
          <div class="bpa-se-o__item">£0.00</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bpa-sei__right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="treatment-option-ext" class="bpa-service-extra__item">
  <div class="bpa-sei__header">
    <div class="bpa-sei__left">
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-checkbox">
        <label class="el-checkbox bpa-form-label bpa-custom-checkbox--is-label bpa-front-form-control--checkbox">
          <span class="el-checkbox__input">
            <span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="">
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-body">
        <div class="bpa-se--heading">1.1ml</div>
        <div class="bpa-se--options">
          <div class="bpa-se-o__item">£0.00</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bpa-sei__right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="treatment-option-ext" class="bpa-service-extra__item">
  <div class="bpa-sei__header">
    <div class="bpa-sei__left">
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-checkbox">
        <label class="el-checkbox bpa-form-label bpa-custom-checkbox--is-label bpa-front-form-control--checkbox">
          <span class="el-checkbox__input">
            <span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="">
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-body">
        <div class="bpa-se--heading">1.1ml</div>
        <div class="bpa-se--options">
          <div class="bpa-se-o__item">£0.00</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bpa-sei__right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

When checked, class is-checked is added to both the span tag and label tag
<div id="treatment-option-ext" class="bpa-service-extra__item">
  <div class="bpa-sei__header">
    <div class="bpa-sei__left">
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-checkbox">
        <label class="el-checkbox bpa-form-label bpa-custom-checkbox--is-label bpa-front-form-control--checkbox is-checked">
          <span class="el-checkbox__input is-checked">
            <span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="">
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="bpa-sei__left-body">
        <div class="bpa-se--heading">1.1ml</div>
        <div class="bpa-se--options">
          <div class="bpa-se-o__item">£0.00</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bpa-sei__right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

How can I make it so that if one the checkboxes is clicked (el-checkbox__original), any of the other checkboxes are unticked, ultimately so that only one checkbox can be checked.
I tried with JQuery but evidently, it does not remove the is-checked from any of the other checkboxes when one of them is clicked
 jQuery.noConflict();
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            console.log("page loaded")
          
                $(".bpa-front-si-card").on('click', function(){
                    console.log("service clicked")  
                });
          
                <!-- after clicking bpa-front-si-card - line above, checkboxes with class el-checkbox__original appear and should listen for checkboxes to be clicked -->
                $(".el-checkbox__original").on('click', function(){
                      $('input.el-checkbox__original').not(this).prop('checked', false).closest("label").removeClass('is-checked').closest("span").removeClass('is-checked');  
                }) 
          
        })}, 6000);


"each having the same ID" That's invalid. Also, why are you using checkboxes when radio buttons were designed for what you're describing?

You should check whether the current checkbox is checked or unchecked.

There's nothing in your code that adds or removes a class, it just changes the checked property.

@j08691 this is using a wordpress plugin and we cannot change the input type to radio unfortunately, not without major changes elsewhere to the code, its simpler if possible to manipulate the behaviour as checkboxes

@Barmar how can I remove the classes from the others, both a label, that does not have 'for' and the span tag, baring in mind they all share the same classes, none have unique ID's

.prop('checked', false).removeClass('is-checked')

@Barmar this only targets the input, not the span tags or labels associated

.closest("label").removeClass('is-checked') and similar for the span

@Barmar thanks, your suggestions seem correct, however, we face an issue we did not realise, this being the checkboxes are not actually loaded into the html until a option prior is selected and renders the checkboxes, so, currently, the script does nothing as the elements are not even there

event binding on dynamically-created elements

@Barmar I have updated the code above, got it working mostly, just cannot figure out how to then run the last function, on the basis of the previous click

your question: remove classes? console shows  it removes classes, you say it doesn't, you struggle to explain things or?

Using a delegated event listener solves the problem:


$("body").on("change",".el-checkbox__original",function(){
 $(".el-checkbox__original").each((i,cb)=>{
  if(cb!=this)cb.checked=false;
  let l=$(cb).closest("label").toggleClass("is_checked",cb.checked);
  l.find("span").eq(0).toggleClass("is_checked",cb.checked);
})
})
span.is_checked {background-color:#0f0;}
label.is_checked {border: 1px solid #0a0;}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="treatment-option-ext" class="bpa-service-extra__item">
  <div class="bpa-sei__header">
<div class="bpa-sei__left">
  <div class="bpa-sei__left-checkbox">
    <label class="el-checkbox bpa-form-label bpa-custom-checkbox--is-label bpa-front-form-control--checkbox">
      <span class="el-checkbox__input">
        <span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="">
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="bpa-sei__left-body">
    <div class="bpa-se--heading">1.1ml</div>
    <div class="bpa-se--options">
      <div class="bpa-se-o__item">£0.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bpa-sei__right">
</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="treatment-option-ext" class="bpa-service-extra__item">
  <div class="bpa-sei__header">
<div class="bpa-sei__left">
  <div class="bpa-sei__left-checkbox">
    <label class="el-checkbox bpa-form-label bpa-custom-checkbox--is-label bpa-front-form-control--checkbox">
      <span class="el-checkbox__input">
        <span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="">
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="bpa-sei__left-body">
    <div class="bpa-se--heading">1.1ml</div>
    <div class="bpa-se--options">
      <div class="bpa-se-o__item">£0.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bpa-sei__right">
</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="treatment-option-ext" class="bpa-service-extra__item">
  <div class="bpa-sei__header">
<div class="bpa-sei__left">
  <div class="bpa-sei__left-checkbox">
    <label class="el-checkbox bpa-form-label bpa-custom-checkbox--is-label bpa-front-form-control--checkbox">label
      <span class="el-checkbox__input">span
        <span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="">
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="bpa-sei__left-body">
    <div class="bpa-se--heading">1.1ml</div>
    <div class="bpa-se--options">
      <div class="bpa-se-o__item">£0.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bpa-sei__right">
</div>
  </div>
</div>



